# Why MagicalRecord is saving data in simulator, but not in the device?

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

This is my save code:

```
func saveEntity() {
        if let fileEnt = self.entity {
            let context = fileEnt.managedObjectContext
            context?.MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println("DB_SAVE_ERROR: \(error)")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

The app is working just fine in the simulator, but it's not working in the device.

```
NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x14e41220) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

Removing the app from the device, did not do the job.

(Latest MagicalRecord installed by cocoapods.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why it is working for you in the simulator. Can you maybe provide some more code regarding the creation and saving usage?

Anyhow, I recommend using the method MR_saveWithBlock, mainly because it saves all parent contexts automatically, which is a very big help once you deal with several contexts in concurrent use.